# Datos dinámicos en JMETER

Tags: rendimiento, pruebas-unitarias, jmeter

grabé un script con blazemeter con el registro de un usuario y todo funciona perfecto, el problema es que cuando quiero hacer la prueba de estress registra al primero, pero el segundo no, pues es el mismo correo, existe alguna manera en la que el dato de email pueda ser dinámico? por ejemplo prueba1@gmail.com... y el siguiente prueba2@gmail.com.... y así pruebaN@gmail.com

¿Se puede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si definieras la petición creando el BodyData que viaja, podrías definir variables que podríás cargar desde un csv.

Por ejemplo

[image: configuracion del request HTTP]

Mira cómo se usan variables en el cuerpo de la petición

```
<amount>${h_amount}</amount>
<channel>${h_channel}</channel>
```

En configuraciones resultantes de grabar con BlazeMeter, [se pueden usar](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) las variables en los campos que señalas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al thread group le puedes añadir un data set CSV

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo CSV deberá tener entonces una fila de encabezado con los nombres de las variables que se usan y luego, las filas con los datos de cada petición

```
h_account,channel,h_amount,h_var4,h_var5,h_var6,h_date,h_var7,h_var8
TEST,123,1,TEST_DEST,10,200.100.52.166,2017-08-19T12:13:47.550-05:00,TEST,Client_TEST
```

Comment: Entonces la grabación de blazemeter no me sirve para esto? (Soy nueva, disculpa la pregunta)

Comment: @PaolaGodoy Perdón, omití la opción para editar la config de blazemeter. Edité la respuesta

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó perfecto con el vidoe tutorial que está ahí!!! Mil gracias

Answer (score -1):

veo que tienes dominio sobre jmeter, por lo que necesito tu ayuda,estoy trantando de aprender a hacer pruebas de estrés pero para ello el puerto del jmeter y del naegador no pueden entrar en conflicto, yo utilizo un servidor proxy empresarial y despues de investigar me entere que había que usar la linea de comandos jmeter -H -P  -u someusername -a someuserpassword -N localhost, pero no logro que la consola me introduzca comandos, para ello vi que tenia que establecer unas variables de entorno en mi sistema pero después de tanto intentar aún no me funciona. Qué podría hacer?
Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/301032)